# Error Using BeautifulSoup Script Executing on Droplet

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, digital-ocean

I have a beautifulsoup script which runs perfectly on my local machine as a Django custom command. However, when I execute the same script as a custom command on my ocean droplet, I get the following nonetype error:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'prettify'

I'm not sure why this script would work on my machine but not on the droplet. As far as I can see I have the same versions of python and django running.

```
        heading = soup.find('h1',class_="gem-c-title__text gem-c-title__text--long")
        heading = heading.prettify()
        d['heading'] = heading
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you install `BeautifulSoup` on your droplet?

Comment: Yes it's installed. In fact the weird thing is that there are bits of code prior to this piece which appear to run correctly. Not sure why it fails on this specific part.

Comment: your `heading` get None

Comment: But on my local machine for the same URL I’m actually getting a result, it shouldn’t be none

Comment: Give an example what you get on local env?

Comment: <h1 class="gem-c-title__text gem-c-title__text--long">
    Minister of State for the Americas statement on Nicaragua
  </h1>

Comment: just try `heading=<p class="gem-c-lead-paragraph "> FCO Minister Sir Alan Duncan deeply concerned by ongoing violence and reports of human rights abuses in Nicaragua. </p>` in droplet for test